# Hide Form in PHP

Tags: php, tabs, hide

I need to hide the following in this block of code, not deleting it's functionality but merely making it not visible to the guest:

```
<style>.NoScript { display: none; }</style>
<noscript>
   <style>.NoScript { display: block; } .YesScript { display: none; }</style>
</noscript>
            <div class="P NoScript">
       <?php echo $Form->RadioList('Type', array('Question' => 'Ask a Question', 'Discussion' => 'Start a New Discussion')); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="YesScript">
       <div class="Tabs">
          <ul>
             <li class="<?php echo $Form->GetValue('Type') == 'Question' ? 'Active' : '' ?>"><a id="QnA_Question" class="QnAButton TabLink" rel="Question" href="#"><?php echo T('Ask a Question'); ?></a></li>
             <li class="<?php echo $Form->GetValue('Type') == 'Discussion' ? 'Active' : '' ?>"><a id="QnA_Discussion" class="QnAButton TabLink" rel="Discussion" href="#"><?php echo T('Start a New Discussion'); ?></a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
```

because right now, two tabs are displayed: one for "Ask a Question" and one for "Start a New Discussion."  How can I, by modifying the code above, hide these from appearing?

Comment: You already dead that with your `<style>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the `visibility` property

```
<style>.NoScript { visibility: hidden; }</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure which you're trying to hide, but it's as simple as

```
<?php if (/* user is not guest */) : ?>
  <div class="Tabs">
      <ul>
         <li class="<?php echo $Form->GetValue('Type') == 'Question' ? 'Active' : '' ?>"><a id="QnA_Question" class="QnAButton TabLink" rel="Question" href="#"><?php echo T('Ask a Question'); ?></a></li>
         <li class="<?php echo $Form->GetValue('Type') == 'Discussion' ? 'Active' : '' ?>"><a id="QnA_Discussion" class="QnAButton TabLink" rel="Discussion" href="#"><?php echo T('Start a New Discussion'); ?></a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If this isn't sufficient, you could set the visibility to hidden with something like:

```
<li class="alldatphpcode" <?php if (/*is a guest*/) echo "style='visibility: hidden;'"?>/>
```

The first one I suppose effectively removes that functionality in the sense that the user could not possibly do it if they were a guest, the second merely stops it form displaying, but will still show up in the source.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using JS to do the hide/display logic, not relying on css buried in noscript blocks. Default the noscript form to visible, the script-dependent one to hidden, then a chunk of JS to flip those states:

```
<style>
    .hiddenform { display: none }
</style>

<div id="nocript">.... form for the JS-deprived</div>
<div id="withscript" class="hiddenform">... form for JS-enabled users</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('withscript').setAttribute('class', ''); // remove hiddenform
   document.getElementById('noscript').setAttribute('class', 'hiddenform');
</script>
```